# script with the phone number to be replaced for that page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom

So I tried this. I put the required code in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number) {        
        var e = document.getElementById("number");         
        e.innerHTML = "";   
        e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
    }; 
</script>
```

And then instead of using:

```
<body onload="_googWcmGet(callback, '0800-123-4567')"> 
<span id="number">0800-123-4567</span> </body>
```

I'm using:

```
<body> <span id="number">0800-123-4567</span> <script type="text/javascript"> 
 window.onload = _googWcmGet(callback, '0800-123-4567'); </script> </body>
```

It errors out with _googWcmGet being undefined. Think this is due to my lack of knowledge of JS/DOM stuff and that I need to cal _googWcmGet outside the body tag some other way?

Comment: Does replacing `window.onload = _googWcmGet(callback, '0800-123-4567')` with `window.addEventListener('load', () => { _googWcmGet(callback, '0800-123-4567')});` solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i replaced <body> <span id="number">0800-123-4567</span> <script type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEventListener('load', () => { _googWcmGet(callback, '0800-123-4567')}); </script> </body>  did not worked

Comment: Where did you define the function _googWcmGet()